# HTML Adding subpages(children)?

Tags: html, url

I don't know if it's the fact I don't know how to phrase it or something, but I can't seem to find out how to add subpages.
I don't mean pages apart from the index, I mean this:
"www.example.com/portfolio" links to "www.example.com/portfolio/art"

rather than:
"www.example.com/portfolio" links to "www.example.com/art"

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which server side language are you using? You need to configure your URL Routing Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use .HTACCESS with URL Rewrite method.

There are quite a few articles out there but you can check this one out;

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

You will still need to create the HTML pages but the display will be different.

Honestly, there are multiple ways to accomplish what you are asking for and one other method is to do it with JQuery. You can change the URL and load the HTML inside the div. The best approach would be to use footer and header as static and load the HTML pages inside the body.

Comment: Right. I'll look into the URL Rewriting method some more, it seems that is more likely to be the route I use. My code is a little messy (bad, I know) so using JQuery might be a little problematic without some organisation. Sadly it doesnt seem as simple as I'd hoped it may be. Thanks anyway!